# Listing Multiple Degrees on CV

Tags: cv

I am using this template to make my CV and I would like to list multiple bachelor degrees.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs

```
\resumeSubheading
  {University of Maryland, College Park}{College Park, MD}
  {Bachelor of Science Degrees in Mathematics}{Aug. 2015-- May 2019}   
  {Bachelor of Science Degrees in Computer Science}{Aug. 2015-- May 2019}
```

But every time I list my degrees, the texts overlap one another. I tried using `\vspace{1mm}` but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the template itself there is no direct way to do it as the `resumeSubHeading` command only take 4 arguments and places them in a table.

You can achieve what you want by adding the `makecell` package to the preamble and inputting your degrees in the following manner:

```
\resumeSubheading
  {University of Maryland, College Park}{College Park, MD}
  {\makecell{Bachelor of Science Degrees in Mathematics\\   
    Bachelor of Science Degrees in Computer Science}}
  {\makecell{Aug. 2015-- May 2019\\
    Aug. 2015-- May 2019}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I ran into the same problem so I thought I'd post my solution. You could also add a modified version of `resumeSubHeading` like so:

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingTwo}[6]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
      \textit{\small#5} & \textit{\small #6} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
```

Then you could define the heading like below:

```
\resumeSubheadingTwo
  {University of Maryland, College Park}{College Park, MD}
  {Bachelor of Science Degrees in Mathematics}{Aug. 2015-- May 2019}   
  {Bachelor of Science Degrees in Computer Science}{Aug. 2015-- May 2019}
```